# Unable to update Bar charts data(Charts 3.05 , Build 24) from a Json in swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, json, bar-chart, swift4

Hi friends im new in ios develpoment  i have created a horizontal bar charts and try to update the data using a json array but im not able to update the data in to my chart. in this chart i am able to increase the count of "Ticket count" but not able to decrease it when we change a "ticket Status"
Eg: i have 12 tickets in that 10 is "Pending Review"  and 2 is "Rejected" 
and when i changed status of one ticket from "Pending Review" to "Rejected"
im getting an out put of "pending Review" count = 10 again,  but "Rejected" count = 3

var ticketStatus = String  //"Accepted", "Closed", "Pending Review", "Rejected"
    var ticketCount = Int

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Int]) {

```
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y:Double(values[i]), data: ticketStatus as AnyObject )
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
           chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
    horizontalBarChartView.legend.enabled = false
    horizontalBarChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    let chartData = BarChartData()
    chartData.barWidth = Double(0.75)
 horizontalBarChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
    chartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.clear

    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    horizontalBarChartView.data = chartData
```

}

```
func showNames(){
    self.ticketStatus = SingletonJson.shared.StringArray
        var counts: [String: Int] = [:]
        self.ticketStatus.forEach { counts[$0, default: -1] += 1 }
        var tktStatusArray: [String] = []
        var countArray: [Int] = []
        for (tktStatus,tktCount) in counts.sorted(by: { $0.0 > $1.0 }) {
            tktStatusArray.append("\(tktStatus)")
            countArray.append((tktCount))
        }
        self.ticketStatus = tktStatusArray
        self.ticketCount = countArray
        setChart(dataPoints: self.ticketStatus, values: self.ticketCount)
    }



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

   self.showNames()
      horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:ticketStatus)
    setChart(dataPoints: self.ticketStatus, values: ticketCount)
    self.horizontalBarChartView.data?.notifyDataChanged()
    self.horizontalBarChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()


}
```

plese help me to solve this issue

Comment: Is there any cache data stored in bar charts ???

Comment: **Try This one it's Working it is a bug of Library I have resolve it.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612972/10150796